# Session variables are undefined after refreshing the page in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm rewriting the backend from PHP to node.js and tried using session variables. Unfortunately, after reloading, `console.log ()` on line 34 does not show the same value as `console.log ()` on line 50 before reloading. The */api/change_theme* endpoint is called on the page when the button is clicked, and then the front-end sends the appropriate data.
What did I do wrong?
Here's my code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const UserSchema = require('./models/user_model')
const urlencodedparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})

require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/whiteboard', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connected');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({
  secret: "1234567890QWERTY",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.theme + ' before')
  if(req.session.theme == undefined){
    req.session.theme = 'dark'
  }
  console.log(req.session.theme + ' after')
  res.render('index',{theme: req.session.theme});
});

app.post('/api/change_theme', urlencodedparser, (req, res) => {
  let frontTheme = req.body.theme
  console.log(frontTheme + ' before')
  if(frontTheme == 'dark'){
    req.session.theme = 'light';
  }else{
    req.session.theme = 'dark';
  }
  console.log(req.session.theme + ' after')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was struggling with this problem for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You never send a response in `/api/change_theme`. This causes your request to hang forever (until timeout, at least). You can check it in DevTools: the request will probably appear as `(Pending)` for a very long time.

`express-session` only saves (replaces) the session data in the DB after the response is sent (after request handler finishes executing). Here, from express' point of view, the handler is never done, so the session is never saved with the new values.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't notice that.